# Simple table creation in HIVE throwing error

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Simple table creation in HIVE not working its throwing the following error
Please help out.

**hive>CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);**

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Comment: You have some issues in the configuration. If you have used mysql to store Hive metadata, make sure its running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple,Your "metastore" is not running or is not properly configured.The metastore is a DB for hive to keep its metadata.Its a Relational DB.There is one inbuilt Derby DB but most distributions use MySQL.